# Assembler file as input for a driver build with the WDK tools

Tags: windows, assembly, build, driver, wdk

How to get an assembler file to be compiled and linked into a driver build.

To clarify a bit

The SOURCES file :

```
TARGETTYPE=DRIVER
DRIVERTYPE=WDM
TARGETPATH=obj

TARGETNAME=bla

INCLUDES=$(DDK_INC_PATH)
TARGETLIBS=$(DDK_LIB_PATH)\ks.lib

SOURCES=x.cpp y.cpp z.asm
```

The problem occurs with the `z.asm file`. `NMAKE` complains that it does not know how to build `z.obj`.

So the question is, how to get the asm file assembled with `build` and linked into `bla.sys`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried the I386_SOURCES?

E.g

```
SOURCES=x.cpp y.cpp
I386_SOURCES=i386\z.asm
```

And putting the file in the i386 directory.
Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms792148.aspx) regarding the SOURCES macro